# Redirect not working inside form handler - webapp2 - GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have a form located at the footer of my base template in Jinja. I call the FormHandler class to process the form to enter the contact info into a database. Then I try to redirect to the home page. The information is getting entered correctly into the database, and the redirect code in the log file says returns a 200 status code. However, the home page never gets loaded. Thanks a lot for your help!

```
class FormHandler(MainHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.name = self.request.get('name')
        self.email = self.request.get('email')
        self.msj = self.request.get('msj')
        message = MsjDB.new_msj(self.name, self.email, self.msj)
        mensajes.put()
        self.redirect('/')

class MainPage(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("home.html", route="home", title="Home")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/formhandler', FormHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Log Console output:

```
INFO     2015-10-28 09:43:24,480 module.py:786] default: "POST /formhandler HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-10-28 09:43:24,503 module.py:786] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16168
```

Comment: The logs suggest the redirection worked fine, looks like you're having problems displaying the response to the `/` request _after_ the redirection.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using polymer's iron-form. I just turned that off and its working, so my guess is that it has something to do with how I'm treating the response to the iron-form.